# Confusion about boundary conditions for a wave equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fourier-series, wave-equation

I have the following wave equation here:

$\frac{\partial u(x,t)}{\partial x^2} -\frac{1}{c^2}\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial t^2}=6$ with the boundary conditions as follows:

$u(0,t)=0$

$u(a,t)=0$

$u(x,0)=0$

$\frac{d(u(x,t)}{dt}|_{t=0}=0$

Okay fine. No problems. So I go ahead and write the total solution $u(x,t)$ as $u(x,t)= U_p(x,t)+u_g(x,t)$ where $U_p(x,t)$ is the particular solution and $u_g(x,t)$ is the homogeneous solution.

So for the particular solution:

$\frac{d^2(u(x))}{dx^2}=6$

If I integrate twice and apply the first two boundary conditions, I get:

$U_p(x)=3x^2-3ax$ which works with the given boundary conditions.

Then I go ahead and attempt to solve the homogeneous solution. So in other words, I get:

$\frac{\partial u(x,t)}{\partial x^2} -\frac{1}{c^2}\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial t^2}=0$

So using the fact that they must both equal some speration constant, I solve the spatial differential equation first and obtain:

$\frac{1}{x}$$\frac{d^2X}{dx^2} -\frac{1}{c^2T}\frac{\partial^2T}{\partial t^2}=0$

So I get:

$\frac{1}{x}$$\frac{d^2X}{dx^2} = \lambda $ and $\frac{1}{c^2T}\frac{\partial^2T}{\partial t^2}=\lambda $

The spatial problem for $\lambda <0$ gives me a non trivial eigenfunction of:

$X_n(x) = A\sin(\frac{n\pi x}{a})$

For the time dependent differential equation:

$\frac{\partial^2T}{\partial t^2} = \lambda c^2 T $

So this means that I get:

$T(t) = c_1 \cos(\frac{c n \pi t}{a}) + c_2 \sin(\frac{c n \pi t}{a})$

So if I multiply the product solutions, I get:

$U_g(x,t) = A_n\cos(\frac{c n \pi t}{a})\sin(\frac{n \pi x}{a}) + B_n\sin(\frac{c n \pi t}{a})\sin(\frac{n \pi x}{a})$

To get the full solution, I just sum it all up so...

$$U_g(x,t) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} A_n\cos(\frac{c n \pi t}{a})\sin(\frac{n \pi x}{a}) + B_n\sin(\frac{c n \pi t}{a})\sin(\frac{n \pi x}{a})$$

Now the problem is that I'm not really sure how to use the last two boundary conditions, from what I am seeing I try to use then and find the Fourier sine coefficients, I get that $A_n$ and $B_n$ are both $0$? That implies I only have a particular function and no homogeneous term. It doesn't feel right to me...

Can someone please help in in understanding how would I use the last two boundary conditions?

Comment: I don't think you're doing anything wrong. It does mean that the Fourier coefficients are all zero because of the zero initial conditions.

Comment: Fair enough. It just feels odd but I suppose it's because the initial conditions are all zero. Thanks!